# Like Operator with comma-separated values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

For example, this is my original table

```
SELECT id, testName FROM tblTest1
```

[image]

Whenever my comma-separated values are in proper way, then I got my result based on my original table.

See this below image:

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(100)
SET @Test='General, Narcotic'

SELECT id, testName 
FROM tblTest1 a 
WHERE ISNULL(a.testName, '') LIKE (CASE WHEN isnull(@Test,'') = '' THEN isnull(a.testName,'') 
                                        ELSE '%'+@Test+'%' END)
```

[image]

But when I am changing the original position of comma separated values, I am not getting any output.

See this below image:

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(100)
SET @Test='Narcotic,General'


SELECT id, testName FROM tblTest1 a 
WHERE isnull(a.testName,'') Like (CASE WHEN isnull(@Test,'') = '' THEN isnull(a.testName,'') 
ELSE '%'+@Test+'%' END)
```

[image]

So, I want the query that I want to pick all the rows whenever my comma separated string the in that row (including the changing comma seprated values not based with original table with `@paramer` is null then pick all the rows)

Comment: Please don't post data or code has an image. Both data and code (SQL) are text, and should be posted as `text`. Ideally data should be provided DDL and DML statements, however, otherwise supply it as tabular formatted `text`. Please take the time to update your post so that we can consume your SQL and data. Thanks.

Comment: Another good example why storing comma separated values in a single row is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single column, using a delimited string.  Use a junction/association table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ....i know but...it's company requirement

Comment: I find it hard to believe a company requires you **store** the data in a denormalised format. perhaps they need it *displayed* as a delimited list, but the display and stored values can (and often are) very different. You might be required to display all dates in your application in the format `dd MMMM yyyy` (i.e. `'07 August 2019'`), but you wouldn't store that value in your database; you'd use a `date` which would store it as a binary value. You'd use your application to control the format of the value. The same should be true here.

Comment: If its really outside of your control, your only option is to normalize the data on the fly (all of it), with some sort of string splitting function, which is going to be sloooow. Better to push back on whoever is providing data like this.

Comment: `General, Narcotic` (with a space) will not match data `General,Narcotic` (without a space). You need to fix your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `IS NULL` and `OR` condition

```
SELECT id, testName
FROM tblTest1 a
WHERE (@test IS NULL OR a.testName LIKE '%'+@test+'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this.

Since you are using SQL 2005 first you need to create a function to split your comma separated value into row like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(@String nvarchar(max), @Delimiter char(1))
RETURNS @Results TABLE (Items varchar(200))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @INDEX INT
DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(max)
-- HAVE TO SET TO 1 SO IT DOESNT EQUAL Z
--     ERO FIRST TIME IN LOOP
SELECT @INDEX = 1
WHILE @INDEX !=0
BEGIN
-- GET THE INDEX OF THE FIRST OCCURENCE OF THE SPLIT CHARACTER
SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)
-- NOW PUSH EVERYTHING TO THE LEFT OF IT INTO THE SLICE VARIABLE
IF @INDEX !=0
SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)
ELSE
SELECT @SLICE = @STRING
-- PUT THE ITEM INTO THE RESULTS SET
INSERT INTO @Results(Items) VALUES(@SLICE)
-- CHOP THE ITEM REMOVED OFF THE MAIN STRING
SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)
-- BREAK OUT IF WE ARE DONE
IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK
END
RETURN
END
GO
```

After that you may use this function to get your desired result

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(100)
SET @Test='Narcotic,General'

select * from (
select items from Split(@test, ',')) as d where d.value like 'na%'
```

Here @test is your table value, and using Split function you are testing with matching expression for same.

I am not saying that this is your final one stop solution, but this is giving just idea for your further process.

Comment: This does *assume* the OP is using SQL Server 2016+.

Comment: i am using....sql server 2005 ...???....so this query will work for me...or not??...

Comment: is this is possible for you to create new function in your database.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 has been completely out of support for over 3 years now, @akhileshsingh . if you really are using such out dated technology, you need to let people know.

Comment: @DarkRob...i am not getting this line....please can you explain me...select * from (
select value from Split(@test, ',')) as d where d.value like 'na%'

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
 varData VARCHAR(50)
 )

 INSERT INTO #temp
 (
     varData
 )
 VALUES
 ('General,Narcotic'),
 ( 'General,ABC')

 DECLARE @Data VARCHAR(50) ='Narcotic,General'
 DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)=''

 SELECT @Query+='varData LIKE ''%''+'''+value+'''+''%'' AND ' 
 FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Data,',')

 SET @Query='SELECT * FROM #temp WHERE '+ SUBSTRING(@Query,1,LEN(@Query)-4)
 EXEC(@Query)

 DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Hey there! Code answers without any context is usually discouraged at stack overflow. Please add some additional information including why and how this answers the OP's question.

Comment: This won't handle the case where you have similar values i.e. where one is a substring of the other e.g. Card and Cardigan - the Cardigan would get picked up when searching for Card as its also LIKE '%Card%'. To avoid this you need to do the string splitting on the whole table as well.

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` was added in SQL Server 2016, but this question is tagged 2005 - this won't work